Im using Xampp and phpmyadmin, why is there no account_locked column in mysql.user
Why is there no account_locked column in mysql.user, when i try to find it using
Select user,host,account_locked FROM mysql.user;
and this error appears
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'account_locked' in 'field list'
I used the Select user,host,account_locked FROM mysql.user; in cmd and expected to see the account_locked column, but an error appeared.

XAMPP has been using mariadb instead of mysql for years. Have you confirmed that mariadb version you have does have this feature? What's the exact versuion of your mariadb server?

The version im using is 10.4.32-MariaDB

As per mariadb's documentation on user account locking, account_locked is in mysql.global_priv table, not in the users table.
Execute
SELECT CONCAT(user, '@', host, ' => ', JSON_DETAILED(priv)) FROM mysql.global_priv 

WHERE user='yourusername';
and account_locked is returned as part of the json.
This further underpins that mysql and mariadb are two different products. You have to know which one you use.
